# CAST - Make string length to be 2 characters long

Tags: sql, string, casting

I need to combine two fields but force the characters of the second string to be 2 characters.

I'm combining a year field and month field and want the result to be YYYY_MM. Forcing any single months (e.g. 1,2,3,4) into a two digit format e.g. (01).

Below is my formula for combining the fields, but I need help making the month two digits.

Thanks, L

```
WITH so_header(soh_build_year,soh_build_week) AS (
          SELECT 2020, 3
UNION ALL SELECT 2020,13
)
SELECT
  CAST(SO_HEADER.SOH_Build_Year AS VARCHAR)
 +'_'
 +CAST(SO_HEADER.SOH_Build_Week AS VARCHAR) as [Build YYYY_WW]
FROM so_header;
```

Comment: It would be better if you would provide real values instead of variables

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Why would you call "month" "week"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out (Syntax: SQL Server)

```
SELECT
  CAST(2019 AS VARCHAR)
 +'_'
 +CAST(format (1, '0#') AS VARCHAR) as [Build YYYY_WW]
```

Replace your values with your variables

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH so_header(soh_build_year,soh_build_week) AS (
          SELECT 2020, 3
UNION ALL SELECT 2020,13
)
SELECT
  CAST(SO_HEADER.SOH_Build_Year AS VARCHAR)
+ '_'
+ SUBSTR(
    CAST(100+SO_HEADER.SOH_Build_Week AS VARCHAR)
  , 2
  , 2
) as Build_YYYY_WW
FROM so_header;
-- out  Build_YYYY_WW 
-- out ---------------
-- out  2020_03
-- out  2020_13
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server *never* use `varchar` (or related types) with no length.  The default varies by context and may not be large enough for what you want.

If you are trying to convert a date to YYYY_MM format, you can use `format()`:

```
select format(getdate(), 'yyyy_MM')
```

I recommend using dates, if they are available.  If you are not using SQL Server, most other databases have similar functionality.

If not, you an simply use:

```
select concat(so_header.SOH_Build_Year, '_'
              right(concat('00', so_header.soh_build_week), 2)
             )
```

`concat()` does not require explicitly converting the values to strings.